# Как проверить существует ли база данных в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток.

Вопрос прост, как проверить существует ли определенная БД (у меня это testtable) в MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выполнить запрос `USE name_of_database` и если вернет ошибку, значит такой нет.
Либо при удалении БД можно использовать конструкцию `IF EXISTS`. Например:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS name_of_database
```

Аналогично и с `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Либо в ПХП можно попробовать воспользоваться функцией. Но сам не пробовал. [Пример](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-name.php#example-1505).

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

Comment: а можно ответ, да или нет (есть или нету), получить как то в виде переменной?

Comment: Еще можно так

    SHOW DATABASES LIKE "db_name";

Если вернет строку с базой то она есть, если нет - то нет

Comment: А так можно получить 1 (если база есть), и 0 (если ее нет):

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE "db_name";

Answer (score 0):

```
$link=mysql_connect("mysqlserver","usr","pass") or die ("Cannot connect");
      mysql_select_db("db_name") or die ("Cannot open DB");
```